# Bind scroll event is not trigger in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, angularjs-directive

Hello I'm working in angularjs1. I created directive for my app now I need to bind scroll event in that directive. In that directive bind **WHEEL** event correctly trigger in Desktop but its not worked in mobile or tablet, so I go with **scroll** bind. But it doesn't work even Desktop
**wheel**

```
 link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
element.bind('wheel', function (e) {
    console.log("scrolling..."); //its work in Desktop
});
})
```

**scroll**

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
element.bind('scroll', function (e) {
    console.log("scrolling..."); //its not work 
});
})
```

How can I handle it, and then ng - click scroll top also not working.if there I need to initialize something
for scroll event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried **touchmove** event for mobile devices?

```
 element.bind('touchmove', function (e)
 {
        console.log("scrolling...");
 });
```

Comment: Mobile devices don't use the same events than regular browsers do. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) link to get more info. BTW if solution works, please mark it. TY

Comment: by use touchmove, how can i detect wheater move up or down. Because i need to hide div when scroll down and show div when scroll up.

Comment: Sorry that was not part of the question, you should open a new question after doing some research. I think answering it kind of violates the rules of SO